# How to Retrieve all possible information about a LinkedIn Account ? (API using C#)

Tags: linkedin-api

I am writting an C# app to make use of [Linkedin's API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/linkedin-api-resource-map).

I want to be able to query "Person" (First Name + Last Name) and retrieve all the possible information about this group of people `with the same name`

I am currently using my own implementation of the [REST API](https://developer.linkedin.com/rest) alongside [People-Search](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/people-search-api) API calls.

Here's an example of a request that I know works:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search:(people:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,picture-url),num-results)?
```

I'm running it with: `first-name=parameter&last-name=parameter after the ? mark`

The problem is, I want to retrieve more information such as Title, Industry, Current-company, current-school etc. Refer [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/people-search-api) for the list of possible parameters.

This notation is what they call [Field Selectors](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/field-selectors)

How do i structure my API Call so i can get all the possible information about someone ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You've already got the notation down, all you need to do is add the rest of the field selectors, nesting them where needed:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search:(people:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,picture-url,industry,positions:(id,title,summary,start-date,end-date,is-current,company:(id,name,type,size,industry,ticker)),educations:(id,school-name,field-of-study,start-date,end-date,degree,activities,notes)),num-results)?first-name=parameter&last-name=parameter
```

Keep in mind that per the [Profile Field docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields), you can only get educations for 1st degree connections of the current user.

Comment: Is there a way to see in the results, which connection is connection from me? I have this one: http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search:(people:(id,first-name,last-name,picture-url,headline,positions:(title,company:(id,name))),num-results)?company-name=[COMPANY]&format=json&count=25 and I can not see which one is first and which one is second dgree.

Comment: i'm not able to retrive educations, skills details and many others..can you suggest the same

Answer (score 42):

Here is the url to get everything for a user Profile:

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,picture-url,industry,summary,specialties,positions:(id,title,summary,start-date,end-date,is-current,company:(id,name,type,size,industry,ticker)),educations:(id,school-name,field-of-study,start-date,end-date,degree,activities,notes),associations,interests,num-recommenders,date-of-birth,publications:(id,title,publisher:(name),authors:(id,name),date,url,summary),patents:(id,title,summary,number,status:(id,name),office:(name),inventors:(id,name),date,url),languages:(id,language:(name),proficiency:(level,name)),skills:(id,skill:(name)),certifications:(id,name,authority:(name),number,start-date,end-date),courses:(id,name,number),recommendations-received:(id,recommendation-type,recommendation-text,recommender),honors-awards,three-current-positions,three-past-positions,volunteer)?oauth2_access_token=PUT_YOUR_TOKEN_HERE

Requires an Oauth2 access token.

Here it is in a nice String list (Java):

```
apiUrl
    + "/v1/people/~:("
        + "id,"
        + "first-name,"
        + "last-name,"
        + "headline,"
        + "picture-url,"
        + "industry,"
        + "summary,"
        + "specialties,"
        + "positions:("
            + "id,"
            + "title,"
            + "summary,"
            + "start-date,"
            + "end-date,"
            + "is-current,"
            + "company:("
                + "id,"
                + "name,"
                + "type,"
                + "size,"
                + "industry,"
                + "ticker)"
        +"),"
        + "educations:("
            + "id,"
            + "school-name,"
            + "field-of-study,"
            + "start-date,"
            + "end-date,"
            + "degree,"
            + "activities,"
            + "notes),"
        + "associations," /* Full Profile */
        + "interests,"
        + "num-recommenders,"
        + "date-of-birth,"
        + "publications:("
            + "id,"
            + "title,"
            + "publisher:(name),"
            + "authors:(id,name),"
            + "date,"
            + "url,"
            + "summary),"
        + "patents:("
            + "id,"
            + "title,"
            + "summary,"
            + "number,"
            + "status:(id,name),"
            + "office:(name),"
            + "inventors:(id,name),"
            + "date,"
            + "url),"
        + "languages:("
            + "id,"
            + "language:(name),"
            + "proficiency:(level,name)),"
        + "skills:("
            + "id,"
            + "skill:(name)),"
        + "certifications:("
            + "id,"
            + "name,"
            + "authority:(name),"
            + "number,"
            + "start-date,"
            + "end-date),"
        + "courses:("
            + "id,"
            + "name,"
            + "number),"
        + "recommendations-received:("
            + "id,"
            + "recommendation-type,"
            + "recommendation-text,"
            + "recommender),"
        + "honors-awards,"
        + "three-current-positions,"
        + "three-past-positions,"
        + "volunteer"
    + ")" 
    + "?oauth2_access_token="+ token;
```

Comment: How would you edit the URL so the data is returned in json format?

Comment: How would you get users email? I have tried using email-address in json, it doesn't return anything? but when i just try to query

<pre>

     APIUrl + "/v1/people/~:("
                        + "id,"
                        + "first-name,"
                        + "last-name,"
                        + "email-address"
</pre>
I get email back. Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: how to get location?

Comment: wHAT'S that? Doesn't work even with a valid access token. `<status>401</status>` and `<message>Invalid access token.</message>`.

Comment: that's very helpful

Comment: Thanks! No example in linked in docs... One of the worst public apis I have delt with

Comment: can you tell me how to get access token, i'm not able to get it, i'm following linked in official documenatation

Answer (score 12):

I use this URL to get everything including email and formatted as json:

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,email-address,last-name,headline,picture-url,industry,summary,specialties,positions:(id,title,summary,start-date,end-date,is-current,company:(id,name,type,size,industry,ticker)),educations:(id,school-name,field-of-study,start-date,end-date,degree,activities,notes),associations,interests,num-recommenders,date-of-birth,publications:(id,title,publisher:(name),authors:(id,name),date,url,summary),patents:(id,title,summary,number,status:(id,name),office:(name),inventors:(id,name),date,url),languages:(id,language:(name),proficiency:(level,name)),skills:(id,skill:(name)),certifications:(id,name,authority:(name),number,start-date,end-date),courses:(id,name,number),recommendations-received:(id,recommendation-type,recommendation-text,recommender),honors-awards,three-current-positions,three-past-positions,volunteer)?format=json

Comment: This is a perfect API call however due to recent changes in their developer program a lot of these fields are not accessible unless you're part of the partner program. 

If you want to test the above call you can use something like this console
https://apigee.com/console/linkedin

Comment: Still works for me right now.  Since I just wanted to know my own data. The apogee console is awesome.

Comment: `message: "Unknown authentication scheme",`

Comment: @DaisyR. You wouldn't happen to know *which* partner program? The descriptions of those programs are written by someone with zero technical background and I can't for the life of me figure out what to qualify for. Job history and education for inclusion in "my site's" profile is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Melvyn I agree my previous company applied and it was rejected so we only had access to basic info. I would try to make this application as strong as possible to integrate full API access to your app and I'm pretty sure this is the link https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply best of luck!

Comment: This apigee.com/console/linkedin is not working.
showing
Error 410: The API Console Service is no longer available