# OAuth Console Not Returning all fields for Honors and Awards

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api

I'm new here, so please bear with me if I am posting to the wrong place.

When using the OAuth console, I am not able to retrieve all the fields under 'Honors & Awards' (URL: http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/honor-awards). It appears I am only able to retrieve the id, name and issuer attributes.

```
<honors-awards total="2">
<honor-award>
<id>2</id>
<name>Test Honors</name>
<issuer>体育爱好者协会</issuer>
</honor-award>
<honor-award>
<id>3</id>
<name>Test Honors2</name>
<issuer>TS</issuer>
</honor-award>
</honors-awards>
```

Also, under the profile fields documentations, certifications appears to have 6 attributes in total, but when returning the XML when using http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/certifications as the URL in the OAuth console, it only returns the following:

```
<certifications total="1">
<certification>
<id>4</id>
<name>Test Certification</name>
</certification>
</certifications>
```

Might there be something wrong that I am doing? Any comment would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For some reason you have to specify fields for all the children of some collections.  See examples of getting the syntax here:

[How to Retrieve all possible information about a LinkedIn Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593144/how-to-retrieve-all-possible-information-about-a-linkedin-account-api-using-c)

If you use the JS API, it will be specified in the .fields such as:

```
.fields(["id", "firstName", "lastName", "certifications:(id,name,authority:(name),number,start-date,end-date)"])
```