# Get full work history and skills from LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to retrieve a person full work history from LinkedIn in addition to the full set of skills and education. According to what I see, I can fetch only the current position. Can someone please guide me on how can I fetch the entire information? 
Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For getting this information you need to be a LinkedIn parther.
Since December 2015, LinkedIn closed part of their API and allow you to get only the user basic info and email.
[This is a short article about it](https://thenextweb.com/dd/2015/02/12/linkedin-takes-aim-developers-plans-lock-apis/)

To see all the possible fields (with the partner access) see this:
[another answer with all the possible fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593144/how-to-retrieve-all-possible-information-about-a-linkedin-account-api-using-c)